# Meshlab / Meshlabserver - How to detect the normal orientation of loaded .ply?

Tags: 3d, meshlab

I have many .ply files.

With some reasons, some of their normal orientations are pointing outside of the object(which is what I want) and some of them are pointing inside the object.

[image]

Does Meshlabserver has a function that can detect the normal orientation of a .ply file, and another function that can unify all the normal to a specific orientation?

By the way, since I am new to 3D ojects, I would like to know what factor determines the normal orientation? Hope someone willing to answer my question.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... photos are of archaeological excavations (foundations and the like), so I'm taking pictures down into a pit to map the stonework foundations. Camera orientations are correct, but color/image information is on the opposite (outside) surface of the convex feature?  Have you tried _Filters -> Camera -> Re-orient vertex normals using cameras_? That seems to (sometimes) work. I haven't figured out the specifics of it yet, though.